# Can not use simple 'dat' example

Tags: go

I am trying to use `Go Postgres Data Access Toolkit` (https://github.com/mgutz/dat). Here is my code (from github):

```
package postgres

import (

    "os"
    "log"

    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v1"
    "gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v1/sqlx-runner"
)

var DB *runner.DB

func init() {
    var err error

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=" + os.Getenv("DBUSER") +
        " password=" + os.Getenv("DBPASS") + " host=" + os.Getenv("DBHOST") +
        " port=" + os.Getenv("DBPORT") + " dbname=" + os.Getenv("DBNAME") + " sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dat.EnableInterpolation = true
    DB = runner.NewDB(db, "postgres")
}
```

As I see in the documentation, now I can use `DB` like this:

```
DB.InsertInto("payments").
    Blacklist("id", "updated_at", "created_at").
    Record(userData).
    Returning("id").
    QueryScalar(&userData.ID)
```

But my `DB` object doesn't have such functions:

[image]

Why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Your code completion just doesn't know how to display embedded methods. Have you tried the code?

Comment: Thank you. It helps me. VS Code code completion works fine. Gogland doesn't :(

Comment: Gogland is stilly super early in development.  Might be better off with Intellij + Go plugin for now.